# Spring Boot Adding external jar in WEB-INF/lib Error

Tags: spring-boot, web, tomcat9

My project structure is like below image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/98TU3.png]

I have added ojdbc14.jar in WEB-INF/lib. But it is not loading the class in class loader and getting classNotFoundException.
Is there any way to add external jar and run Spring Boot app. (Without installing as MAVEN dependecies)
I am using spring-boot:run command to start the server.

Comment: What is wrong with adding as maven/gradle dependency?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way of doing that would be to add it as a dependency.

I suggest you take a look at [dependencies chapter](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#dependencies) of Maven for how to add the a dependency to the project.
You can just open the `pom.xml` and add in inside the `<dependencies>` tag:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

That way not only you use Maven as intended and keep dependency management to it, but you also avoid hitting similar issues.